# Convergence of a series containing logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm stuck on the following problem: for what values of $\alpha$ the following sum is convergent:$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(k)^\alpha}$$
If the series is convergent, there will be a constant $M$ for which
$S(\alpha\ge M)\lt\infty$, but how is it possible to calculate $M$?
Tanks.

Comment: @gt6989b: I forgot to write $\alpha\gt 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for all positive values of $\alpha$, $(\ln{k})^{\alpha} < k$ for sufficiently large $k$.    This is because $x^{\alpha} < e^x$ when $x > 0$ for sufficiently large $x$.  Thus, there is no value of $\alpha$ for which the sum converges, by comparison with the divergent sum having summand $1/k$ (i.e., the harmonic sum). Clearly, there is also no negative value of $\alpha$ for which the sum converges as well.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it diverges for $\alpha \leq 0$ since if $\alpha = 0$ we are summing ones, and if $a < 0$ it's even worse than that :).

For $\alpha > 0$ note that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^\alpha(x)}{x} = 0
$$
by repeated application of L'Hospital's Rule, and so
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{\ln^\alpha(x)} > \int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x} = \infty
$$
and the series diverges by the integral test.